# Unified data API Design Approach

Tags: api, reporting, data-visualization, data-warehouse

I'm trying to build a unified data access layer for my company.  The data is not too big (around 250 GB) and comes from several sources:

1. Tiny binary files (1-2kb) that are generated continuously at the rate of around 4,000 per day.  These comprise the majority of data (~220 GB)
2. MySQL Database tables with user data.  Less frequently updated (~20-30GB)
3. CRM data that need to be accessed through the CRM API.

Now all this data is related in one way or another.  Users want to aggregate data from multiple sources and query them.  The solution should cater to semi-technical people like PMs and external customers.

The question: what is the best approach to aggregate all the data and keep it up to date?

1. A data warehouse that combines everything and allows for aggregation and statistical analysis (something that's definitely needed).
2. An API on top of each data source that transforms the data as appropriate and allows for APIs to query each other to generate meaningful aggregations.  This has the disadvantage of lacking proper visualization tools out of the box.
3. Something else???

Answer (score 1):

Simple try it!
Start with some elementary queries in option 2. You will see quickly if it works. My expectation with three different sources (binary files, relational DB and API) are rather limited.
Proceed with option 1 - start with defining the target data model (the data warehouse tables) and check if they support the required queries.
After that decide the refresh mode for the sources (streaming, incremental refresh, full refresh).
Try to get as soon as possible a feedback from the customers!